# Nicedit upload images locally fails

Tags: php, javascript, upload, nicedit

This is how I call the editor:

```
new nicEditor({
           buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','upload'],
           iconsPath:'img/nicedit.png',
           uploadURI : 'http://server.com/integracion/files/nicUpload.php'
}).panelInstance(textareaId);
```

And the .php file exists ( and I the one in the [Docs](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/515/Configuration%20Options), and I updated the target paths )

```
/* I want them here http://server.com/integracion/files/uploads/ so... */   
    define('NICUPLOAD_PATH', './uploads'); // Set the path (relative or absolute) to
                                              // the directory to save image files                  
    define('NICUPLOAD_URI', '/uploads');   // Set the URL (relative or absolute) to
                                              // the directory defined above
```

But I on response when upload completes (and of corse an alert from nicedit..)

```
<script>
        try {
            top.nicUploadButton.statusCb({"error":"Invalid Upload ID"});
        } catch(e) { alert(e.message); }
    </script>
```

what am I missing?

-EDIT

I think the problem might be in the php file:

```
$id = $_POST['APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS'];  /* APC is installed and enabled */
if(empty($id)) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

Comment: What version of the library are you using? The latest one uses an XHR2 request to upload the image, so it is possible that you will need to adjust your php code.

Comment: I am using the current version on their site @aliem

Comment: @aliem any idea where can i reaad more?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

FINAL EDIT:

I have managed to make this work!

**Here is an working example:**
http://simplestudio.rs/yard/nicedit/

**Uploaded images are going to be stored here:**
http://simplestudio.rs/yard/nicedit/images/

**And here is the whole code, just unpack it and put on your server, mainly I needed to adjust nicEdit.js because it had some issues.**
http://simplestudio.rs/yard/nicedit/nicedit.rar

Just make your code with that js file and by looking at my example, it will work :)

- Also you need to have php APC installed so that this script can work:
  http://php.net/manual/en/apc.installation.php

If you by any mean have some problems I am here to solve it.

- I will not delete this example on my server so that everybody who have this issue can freely download it...

Comment: I don't want the full panel.. tried absolute path and didnt work.. still invalid id error..

Comment: It doesn't work for me. did you just change the .js file?  this is what i get when selecting an image (the .php is not even called) http://imm.io/GxHW It wold be easier if you could let us know what did you actally change

Comment: As you can see on my server it works perfectly... I am now at work so I cant think about it now. I will look at it later this day. Did you tried just to unpack my whole script and try it on your server?

Comment: There seems to be a js error in chrome when you select the editor. good answer tho, nice that some one has got this to work

Comment: Do you even have APC installed on php?

Comment: @DusanRadojevic yes i do. its said in my question! it works now, but a bit differently. I don't het the progress bar and i get a weird language message.. thanks dough!

Comment: If you want to change the "weird message" just go to line about 1406 in nicEdit.js and change text and URL to image it goes after this "this.myStatus.setContent('" so you can search for that also. I ti easy to find it and adjust text to what ever you need... What is bounty status, are you going to give a prize, I don't know the procedure :(

Comment: Download URL really dead. No updates while I'm dying

Answer (score 2):

The code responsible for image upload is the method `uploadFile`, it is looking for `uploadURI` option parameter.

You will need to modify `onUploaded` event handler to parse your custom response instead of the imgur's one ([sample](http://pastie.org/4902518)). By default it expects at least `{"upload": { "links": {"original": "http://..."}, "image": {"width": "123" } }}`.

I'm sorry but I can't help with the [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) handling server side with PHP.

For more information you can try out the demo page on the nicEdit [web site](http://nicedit.com/demos.php) using Firebug or WebInspector to snoop the network requests, and, of course, the source code.

Comment: *by default it expects* - is what helped me to solve this. I watched the imgur json and copied the array and inserted my own values, now nicedit is satisfied and I can use my own upload service.